# Is it possible to use an offset and limit by cloud_firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have huge data and I need to bring ten items every time a user scrolls down, and I collect them together in my code, is there any method I can use to get this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called pagination, and it's discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Firestore pagination does not support numeric offsets.  You have to get the next page based on information in the last document in the prior page.  That's what `startAfter()` is for when building a query.

Comment: What should we do to go to page 4th from page first?

Answer (score -3):

If you want to paginate your data with Firebase, you could do something like this (in JavaScript):

```
let database = admin.firestore;
let snapshot = await database.collection('items')
    .limit(5)
    .offset(10)
    .get();
```

This code will retrieve five items following the first ten. It works, but Firebase's official documentation recommends against it, adding "you still get billed for all the reads that you're offsetting." While not ideal, it's not a terrible option for pagination, assuming your average user isn't regularly accessing pages on the fringe side of your application.

Alternatively, you can follow this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) for a more efficient option.

Comment: there is no offset

Comment: They are talking about the admin sdk